# Can You Wrap a ViewEntry into an instance of DominoViewEntry?

Tags: java, xpages

I know you can convert a Document to a DominoDocument (the Java equivalent of NotesXspDocument) by using `DominoDocument.wrap()`. And thanks to Mastering XPages I know DominoViewEntry is the Java equivalent of NotesXspViewEntry.

It seems that `DominoViewEntry` doesn't have a corresponding `wrap()` method, like DominoDocument does. I can see it extends `AbstractDominoViewEntry`, which also doesn't have a `wrap()` method. So how do you convert a ViewEntry to a `DominoViewEntry`?

It seems like this could be a useful object to store to scope or a Java object, because it converts all values accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to create a DominoViewEntry by yourself?

```
var v:NotesView = database.getView("All Documents");
var entry:NotesViewEntry = v.getAllEntries().getFirstEntry();
var wrapped:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntry = new com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntry( entry, database.getTitle(), "Position");
```

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't thought of a basic constructor. That works beautifully.